# osmosis extract bus_stop not working

Tags: extract, openstreetmap, osmosis

On overpass turbo this query gives a perfect representation of the bus_stop over a city

```
node
[highway=bus_stop]
({{bbox}});
out;
```

but after downloading an osm file over the same city on geofabrik, this osmosis command doesn't give the same result 
  osmosis --read-xml rhone-alpes-latest.osm --node-key-value keyValueListFile=POI.txt --write-xml output-nodes.osm
with POI.txt containing

```
public_transport.stop_position
public_transport.platform
public_transport.station 
railway.halt
railway.station
railway.subway_entrance 
railway.tram_stop
highway=bus_stop
```

The result is far from the one on overpass, giving less nodes. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Try to evaluate which bus stops are included in your osmosis result and which don't. They must differ somehow. Also it is unlikely that your custom bbox covers really the same area as the rhone-alpes extract.

Comment: I have tried on a small city included in the bbox, on turbopass and after extraction from the .osm file. I don't have this problem by using --tf accept-nodes highway=bus_stop, which gives the right result, so I don't really understand the use of --node-key-value.